# Binding XamDataGrid field definitions to view model

Tags: wpf, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I am attempting to build an application that will show different columns in the same XamDataGrid for different Projects. Here is an example:

```
public class Project
{
  public ICollection<Person> People { get; private set; }
  public string DisplaySpec { get; private set; }
}

public class Person{
{
  public Name Name { get; set; }
}

public class Name
{
  ... a bunch of dynamic properties that vary by project...
}
```

I can look up the properties for each Name dynamically with no problem, and if I write Xaml and compile it in the actual executable I can display them. But each project has a different list of fields to bind to, and I want them to be able to inject the field names to display.

Is there any easy manner in which I can allow them to specify the name of the fields that they want to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fields themselves can't be bound.  Your best options are to either to auto generate the fields or to have a method in code that would add the fields needed dynamically.  If you are looking to have a solution that you can use a binding in XAML with you could put the logic to add the fields into a [behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff725476%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) on the grid that exposes a property that you could bind your list to.

To auto generate the fields you would need to set the AutoGenerateFields on the [FieldLayoutSettings](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WPF/Current/CLR4.0/?page=InfragisticsWPF4.DataPresenter.v12.2~Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.FieldLayoutSettings~AutoGenerateFields.html) to True.